# Vectorize for loop over data frame in R

Tags: r, coding-style

I have a data frame with three columns: ref, target, distance.  Each ref has a measured distance to the same set of targets and I would like to get a vector of minimum distances for each ref.  Right now I am doing this with a for loop, but it seems like there ought to be a way to vectorize this.

Here's my code:

```
refs <- levels(data$ref)

result <- c()
for (ref in refs) {
    # Find the minimum distance for observations with the current ref
    # but be sure to protect against ref == target!
    best_dist <- min(data[data$ref == ref & data$target != ref,]$distance)
    result <- c(result, best_dist)
}
```

Am I doomed by having my data frame set up this way or is there a good way to vectorize this?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never grow an object within a loop using `c`, `cbind`, `rbind`. The object will be copied every time.
Instead preallocate to the correct size (or some overestimate if the result is fluid).

That being said, an loop is not required here

I like `data.table`s for memory efficiency and coding elegance.

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(data)


 DT[ref != target, list(bestdist = min(distance)), by = ref]
```

---

if ref and target are factor columns with different levels (as suggested in the comment), then either make them have identical levels, or convert to character

```
 DT[as.character(ref) != as.character(target),  list(bestdist = min(distance)), by = ref]
```

Comment: This seems to not work quite right as is.  I get the following error when trying this: **Error in Ops.factor(ref, target) : level sets of factors are different**

However, **DT[, list(bestdist = min(distance)), by = ref]**
Does produce output, but without the ref!= target check.

Comment: That did the trick!  I should have made it clear that ref and target are strings.  Thanks!

Comment: They aren't character strings, they are factors with (perhaps different) level structures.